Do Inductors and Capacitors cause phase shifts in Current or in Voltage? (AC power source)
In some literature they say that the current in a circuit shifts +-90 degrees due to the presence of capacitors or inductors (AC power supply). But in other places they treat current as unchanging and voltage as being phase shifted. With resistors there is no phase shift but just a decrease in current and not voltage. I was taught that voltage was the "cause" and current is the "response" so it makes sense to me that current is the thing being phased and messed around with.
Below is a phasor diagram (for a problem I'm working on) of voltages with current being along the x-axis. As you can see, we track the voltages of the components instead of the currents which is confusing to me since current is what we are interested in, more specifically, the phase change induced onto the current. Here the current is almost assume constant as it is seen on the x-axis! What am i missing here?


It depends where you look, voltage is phase shifted against current, but this you could also interpret as current is phase shifted versus voltage. In your picture you see I shifted bei $+\phi$ u shifted by $-\phi$

In your example it looks as though the current is the reference phase and that is most probably because you have a series inductor, capacitor and resistor circuit.
Those components being in series means that the current passing though each of them is the same, both in terms of magnitude and phase.
For an equivalent parallel circuit it would be the voltage which was probably chosen as the reference phase as the voltage across each of the components would be the same.

Statement from the website:
The current is of the same size on all the components, the phasor of current $I_{\rm m}$ is therefore the same for all the components and is usually drawn in the positive direction of the x-axis.

Ah, so, the voltage or current can both be undergoing phase shift depending on the conditions? (whether its series or parallel) One question then, if we have a series dlc circuit there would be a drop in voltage across components so why do these online sources only mention the phase difference that conductors and capacitors cause and not the voltage drop?

Also, is it possible for our reference phase to be voltage even though it's a series RLC circuit and how? (if you can answer this, i think all be a lot clearer to me)

$\dots$ is it possible for our reference phase to be voltage even though it's a series RLC circuit and how? Read off the appropriate phase angle off the phasor diagram or  rotate the phasor diagram to position the required voltage phasor along the x-axis.

\dots$ why do these online sources only mention the phase difference that conductors and capacitors cause and not the voltage drop? In your phasor diagram $U_{\rm m}$ is the applied voltage.

But if the voltage is being phased we can turn it to a reference because its different everywhere

The phase s of all the different voltages will be relative to one of the voltages.

thanks for these explanations i think i understand the topic more thoroughly now. But if all it relative here why make the reference phasor current in the case of a series circuit and voltage in the case of parallel circuit. How did you know that i was dealing with a series circuit because of the current being reference? Is there any inherent advantage to this? thanks again.

I agree that current is due to the application of voltage, however, there is one special case you should consider.
In resonant LC circuits the voltage across one of the components can be greater than the applied voltage, and so perhaps in these cases it is worth considering the current across a component as being the 'source' of the voltage. - see for example the discussion here


I was taught that voltage was the "cause" and current is the "response" so it makes sense to me that current is the thing being phased and messed around with.

In circuit theory, there is a principle of duality that says neither voltage nor current is more fundamental than the other. We can treat either voltage or current as the "cause" and determine the other as the "effect" and the result of our calculations will be the same.
In some circuits (for example when there is an ideal or near-ideal voltage source present) it may be easier to treat voltage as cause and current as effect. In other circuits (for example when an ideal or near-ideal current source is present) it is easier to treat current as the cause and voltage as the effect.
Neither method is "more correct" than the other.

Here the current is almost assume constant as it is seen on the x-axis! What am i missing here?

You haven't shared the whole problem that the diagram is meant to explain.
Perhaps this circuit is excited by an ideal current source.
Or perhaps they chose to analyze the circuit assuming 0 phase for the current, because the elements are in series and all share the same current.

The circuit is an in series dlc circuit

@user15755358, 1. Do you mean RLC circuit? 2. Is it specified what source is driving it? 3. What question was being asked about it (for example, are we trying to find its impedance)?

Yes sorry I meant RLC circuit, the question is here: https://physicstasks.eu/1540/series-rlc-circuit we are looking for impedance. I am wondering why they chose to draw voltage vectors onto the phase diagram instead of current phasors (look at the pic in post). If it doesn't matter, what would the graph look like if we used current phasors instead?

Can you elaborate what you meant with "In some circuits (for example when there is an ideal or near-ideal voltage source present) it may be easier to treat voltage as cause and current as effect."

@user15755358, if you have a current source and a resistor forming a circuit, you treat the current source as the "cause" and the voltage produced across the resistor as the "effect". Because the current is what is fixed in advance and the voltage is what you need to calculate.

In fact, every time you call that device a "resistor" you are making current the cause and voltage the effect, because Ohm's law for resistors is V=IR. V is the result and I and R are the givens that you use to calculate. If you want to make voltage the cause and current the effect you should call that device a conductor and write I = GV (where G is the conductance). Same device, two different ways to look at it.
